# Android - Couchbase lite - DAO - MyClass extends Document

Tags: android, design-patterns, dao, couchbase-lite

I'm working on an Android application using Couchbase lite.
Should I have my classes extending `com.couchbase.lite.Document` ?

Pros: DAO is integrated in class.

Cons: - every object is linked to a document, if we want a new object, we must create a new document in couchbase? - anything else?

For example:

```
public class UserProfile extends Document {

    public UserProfile (Database database, String documentId);

    public Map<String, Object> getProperties();

    public boolean isModified();

    public boolean update() throws CouchbaseLiteException {
        if (isModified()) {
            super.putProperties(getProperties());
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend extending Document.  Instead, either just use Maps, or use something like the Jackson JSON library to create POJOs.  I usually create a simple helper class to wrap the database operations (including replication, if you're using that).

Off the top of my head, I wouldn't do it because subclassing doesn't fit well with some of the ways you retrieve documents, documents are somewhat heavy-weight objects, and the preferred way to update takes into account the possibility of conflicts, which would be much more difficult.  (See [this blog post](https://blog.couchbase.com/better-updates-couchbase-lite/) for a discussion of that last point.)

I've never tried to work around these issues in a subclassing approach, but it seems pretty certain to be more pain than it's worth.